# One of our toilets refills VERY slowly - takes 15-20 minutes after flushing.

Tags: plumbing, toilet

Note: Like another user's query, our bowl fills okay, but the tank refills very slowly - takes 15-20 minutes.
We can't detect any leaks. I've adjusted the water valve. I've put a brick in the tank to raise the water level per someone's suggestion. I can't detect any issues with the flush handle or any of the components in the tank.  However, understand: Both my husband and I are totally UNKNOWLEDGEABLE about this sort of thing. We managed to change the flush valve a few months ago, and I think he changed the entire interior mechanism as well - but beyond that, we're helpless!  We simply can't afford a plumber(still paying off a $10,000 water re-route from two years ago). 
Ideas?

Comment: Did you check the water flow from the supply when changing the valve? Run the hose into a bucket and open it up for a few seconds. If that's ok, and you changed the fill valve inside the toilet, then either the flapper isn't seating for a while after flushing, or there is debris in the fill valve you need to clean out. You'll need to open the lid after a flush to see if it's the former.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What might be causing our cistern to fill very slowly?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/9998/2196)

Comment: If the shutoff valve is a multi-turn valve, they have a tendency to not open all the way after not being used for a long time.  You'll want to make sure the valve is opening, and that water is not simply trickling through the valve. What does the flow look like coming from the fill valve?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the old valve was replaced for just not shutting off & this is only happening after the new toilet valve went in. Then yes, it's debris in the line that ruined the new valve, likely from operating the shut-off valve. The toilet valve should be replaced again after flushing the supply line while opening & closing the shut-off valve to make sure all debris is gone.

You may want to turn the house main down a bit, you just want to flush the line (turn on a faucet closest to the main) & turn the main mostly closed so the faucet drops its flow to half but not less, you still want to scrub out the debris pretty good.

***** THE MAIN may also have debris so remove the faucet's aerator & operate the main until water runs clear.*****